# how to write a task that performs appSettings.json transforms using MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-deployment

I have a ASP .NET Core application that I want to deploy to 2 different environments: 1) Staging, 2) Production. I have the following files in my project that contains database connectionStrings:

```
appSettings.json
appSettings.staging.json
appSettings.production.json
```

lets say, the name of connectionString is "MyDb". I want the ability to replace the value of MyDb in appSettings.json with one in appSettings.production.json if the build is run for Production and with appSettings.staging.json if the build is run for staging.

How can I do that? A step by step example would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to write a task that performs appSettings.json transforms using MSBuild?

You can add a custom task `ReplaceFileText` into the project file.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</Project>`, place below scripts:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceFileText" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <OutputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <MatchExpression ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <ReplacementText ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
            File.WriteAllText(
                OutputFilename,
                Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(InputFilename), MatchExpression, ReplacementText)
                );
          ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithProduction" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Production'" AfterTargets="Build"> 
    <ReplaceFileText
      InputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      MatchExpression="MyDb"
      ReplacementText="MyDbProduction" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithProduction" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='staging'" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ReplaceFileText
      InputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      MatchExpression="MyDb"
      ReplacementText="MyDbstaging" />
  </Target>
```

The above example replaces "`MyDb`" with "`MyDbstaging`" or "`MyDbProduction`" in the file `appSettings.json`.

Besides, in order to be able to re-use this task without the need to manually restore the value to "`MyDb`" in the `appSettings.json` file after each modification, we could add a another task to restore this value:

```
  <Target Name="RestoreJsonFile" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy
            SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\BackupJsonFile\appsettings.json"
            DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)"
        />
  </Target>
```

Back up that `appSettings.json` in the back up folder `BackupJsonFile`, then copy it to replace the one that has been modified.

So the final custom task should be:

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceFileText" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <OutputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <MatchExpression ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <ReplacementText ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
            File.WriteAllText(
                OutputFilename,
                Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(InputFilename), MatchExpression, ReplacementText)
                );
          ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="RestoreJsonFile" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy
            SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\BackupJsonFile\appsettings.json"
            DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)"
        />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithProduction" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Production'" AfterTargets="RestoreJsonFile"> 
    <ReplaceFileText
      InputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      MatchExpression="MyDb"
      ReplacementText="MyDbProduction" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithstaging" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='staging'" AfterTargets="RestoreJsonFile">
    <ReplaceFileText
      InputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json"
      MatchExpression="MyDb"
      ReplacementText="MyDbstaging" />
  </Target>
```

[image]

BTW, if replace the value of MyDb in `appSettings.json` is not your only option, you can try to use `appSettings.production.json` if the build is run for Production instead of replacing the value in `appSettings.json`. See [Config transformations in ASP.NET Core](https://blog.elmah.io/config-transformations-in-aspnetcore/) and [Appsettings.json configuration in ASP.Net Core Web API](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/appsettings-json-configuration-in-asp-net-core-web-api/) more detailed info.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After following the above steps, I changed the active solution configuration to 'Production' and built the project and did not see any change in appSettings.json file.

Comment: @Dev_Net, It is my fault. I have double copy the target name with `TransformsWithProduction`, now I updated it, you can check it, and I have test it on my side, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Leo, that worked without any problem. A couple of things: 1) How can I replace the whole section named 'connectionStrings' in appSettings.json with the same section in appSettings.Production.json or appSettings.Staging.json ? 2) is this possible to run these build tasks only when I have to publish the code, and not on each build ?

Comment: @Dev_Net, For the question1), yes, you can. Just need replace the double quote with `&quot;`. For the second, I am afraid not. That because the condition is `'$(Configuration)'=='Production'`, this value could not transfer to publish process, only support by build process.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: How can I use NewtonSoft.Json within a build task?